# RgexPattern, can't get it working

Tags: .net, regex, json, parsing

I have the following pattern which searches for "timer": till } is found:

```
(?<="timer":)[^}]*(?=\})
```

I need that to be modified so that it searches for "timer": till } OR , is found. So, if I have:

```
bc7","timer":20,"referrer":"<default>"},
```

20 will be matched, and if I have:

```
com","timer":18}
```

18 will be matched, with the same pattern.

Comment: What is your actual; expected match?

Comment: I have tried this one: (?<="timer":)[^},]*(?=[\x2C\x7D])  Is it correct or is not optimal?

Comment: Don't you are parsing JSON with REGEX ?

Comment: Please update your question to include the nominal output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json). regex are not the right tool to parse json, instead use a proper JSON parser.

All modern language including shell (see [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)), python, perl, ruby, go, java and such have bindings to properly parse json inputs.

Comment: The best is to use JSON, it's right, but my assembly is .net framework 2.0 output and it does not include any json parser. Using the JSON.NET Library would increase my bin size in 500 kb so I prefer using regex, as size is ABSOLUTELY importabt.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
(?<=\"timer\":)[^},]*(?=[\x2C\x7D])

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
"timer":(\d+)
```

The timer value will be in group 1.